# How can I make a span clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, model-view-controller

I have this code:

```
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    @Html.TextBox("text", Model.Search.text, new {placeholder = Html.T("Поиск"), @class = "form-control"})
```

and as a result this one:

[image: search panel]

It's work fine if user type some text and press Enter. Search work fine. But the "search" button not works. It's just stay and not clickable. How do I make "search" button clickable without losing appearance?

Comment: Maybe you can add a click event listener to the span? You can find an example in the MDN documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Assuming the input field is wrapped in a `form` element, you can change the `span` to `input` or `button` with attribute `type="submit"`.

Comment: what is this syntax. A new templating engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the onclick event. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" onclick="myFunction()"></span>
@Html.TextBox("text", Model.Search.text, new {placeholder = Html.T("Поиск"), @class = "form-control"}
```

`myfunction` can be the function that triggers the submit on your input.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an id to the span element, and then in a js file attach an event to that id when you click it, and when that happens trigger the funcionality.

Example `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id = "icon"></span>`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#icon").click(function(){
    
    alert("Hi");
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id = "icon">Hello, click me!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$this->validate($request, [
           'name' => 'required|string|exists:products,name',
       ]);
```

I hope this works!

Comment: additional option :'name' => 'required|exists:App\Models\products,name'